# Download file and connect: if one of them fails, go to step one

Tags: c#, beginner

My program....

1. Downloads a file
2. Connects to a server

If one of these operations were to fail, the program stalls for a minute and goes back to step one.

So, I would avoid recursion and the use of global variables. I think I did the first one right, but I need help to avoid the second one. What would I do if I need to "receive" variables from a function to a `while` loop?

```
public class Globals
{
    public static int sockConn = 0;
    public static bool sockRetry = false;
}

static void getInfo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(INFO_HOST + INFO_PATH);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            string content;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            string[] contentArray = content.Split(':');

            if (contentArray.Length == 2)
            {
                string serverIp = contentArray[0];
                string serverPortStr = contentArray[1];

                int serverPort = 5000;
                Int32.TryParse(serverPortStr, out serverPort);

                while (Globals.sockConn == 0)
                {
                    if (Globals.sockRetry == false)
                    {
                        connect(serverIp, serverPort);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Globals.sockRetry = false;
                        Thread.Sleep(60000);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                continue;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            continue;
        }
    }
}

static void connect(string serverIp, int serverPort)
{
    Globals.sockConn = 1;

    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIp, serverPort);
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nwStream);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nwStream);

        Globals.sockConn = 2;

        string inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            ParseMessage(writer, serverIp, inputLine);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Globals.sockRetry = true;
        Globals.sockConn = 0;
        return;
    }
}

public static void ParseMessage(StreamWriter Writer, string serverIp, string msg)
{
    // simple parsing
    // function to upload conf file with using serverIp string
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Globals & Public Static Fields

> ```
> public class Globals
> {
>     public static int sockConn = 0;
>     public static bool sockRetry = false;
> }
> ```

You put a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) tag on your post, so I'm going to try do be gentle: ***please* kill this, with fire!** :)

A non-static class that's called `Globals`, that only contains public static fields, smells. Why? Because in an *object-oriented* paradigm language, *globals stink* and make everything more complicated than need be.

> **Side note: naming.**
>
> C# coding standards recommend using `camelCase` for local variables and parameters. Public members should be `PascalCase`.

---

#### OOP Basics #1: *Encapsulation*

Avoid exposing public fields. Always. Not because they're `static` - because they're *fields*. Fields belong to a class instance (or, when they're static, they belong to a *type*), and should be considered *implementation details* that the outside world **never** needs to know about. Consider systematically *encapsulating* fields with properties:

```
private int sockConn = 0;
public int SocketConnectionCount { get { return sockConn; } set { sockConn = value; } }
```

In this case, there isn't really a gain with the backing field - so you can have the C# compiler make one for you, leaving you with a cleaner code file:

```
public int SockConnectionCount { get; set; }
```

This is called an "auto-property". Compiler magic! :)

---

#### Thinking in Objects

Think in terms of *responsibilities* - what is your code accomplishing?

- Creating and sending a web request, receiving a web response.
- Streaming the response into a string.
- Splitting the string into an array; element 0 being the IP, element 1 being the port.
- Connecting to the IP/port and receiving a message through TCP/IP.
- Parsing the received message.

Break this down into their own methods/functions that do **one** thing, so simply that they can't possibly do it wrong. Then regroup the related ones into their own classes, and *instantiate* them.

---

Wait, something caught my eye and *needs* to be addressed:

> ```
> int serverPort = 5000;
> Int32.TryParse(serverPortStr, out serverPort);
> ```

`out serverPort` is an *out* parameter - the method it's passed into **has to initialize it** before it returns. In other words, the `5000` is never used. And you're never using the `TryParse` method's return value either (it's a Boolean that tells you whether the parse succeeded or not). `out` parameters are the only time you can pass an uninitialized variable into a method and have nothing to worry about. The above lines should read something like this:

```
int serverPort;
var result = int.TryParse(serverPortStr, out serverPort);
// do something if result is true
```

Avoid Hungarian-ish postfixes (and prefixes as well); If you need to specify that a variable is a `String`, it's because you haven't found a truly meaningful name for it. Notice I called the `TryParse` method on the `int` type. It's the very same thing as `Int32` - in fact, `int` is a C# language shortcut for `System.Int32`; both are perfectly interchangeable... but it's better to choose one, and stick to it, for consistency's sake! :)

Comment: Whoa! Thank you for all the information, really. I'll read this a few times to make sure everything is right! Thanks again.

Comment: @MiguelRipoll you might like to post your revised code as a new question after taking Mug's great advice :)

Comment: I fixed all your points, thanks for pointing up the bug from TryParse BTW. It works perfectly and is so organized! @mjolka Thanks, I'll re-check everything a few days and publish it again :)